# SharePoint 2010 Rest query for Lookup fields

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, lookup-column

I am writing a REST query to retrieve data from child parent list.

States is the parent list with "Title" column.
LocalGovernment is the child list with "State_Territory(InternalName) and State / Territory(Display name)" as a lookup column.

Following is the output without any filter
[image]

I am trying to get "title" of the state from the parent list.

**Query  = /_vti_bin/listdata.svc/LocalGovernmentAreas?$select=State_Territory/Id&$expand=State_Territory/Id**

Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.LocalGovernmentAreasItem' does not have a property named 'State_Territory' - I am using "State_Territory" because it is the internal name.

I have also tried

**/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/LocalGovernmentAreas?$select=StateTerritory/Id&$expand=StateTerritory/Id**

but error is

Only properties specified in $expand can be traversed in $select query options. Property

I have also tried

**/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/LocalGovernmentAreas?$select=State_Territory/Id&$expand=State_Territory**

but error is

Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.LocalGovernmentAreasItem' does not have a property named 'State_Territory'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error:

> Only properties specified in $expand can be traversed in $select query
>   options. Property .

occurs since it seems the $expand query option syntax:

`$expand=<lookupfield>/<projected property>` is **not supported** in SharePoint **2010** REST Interface.

**Solution**

Use the following query instead:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/LocalGovernmentAreas?$select=State_Territory/Id&$expand=State_Territory
```

Comment: that too did not work, original question updated with query and error.

Comment: "StateTerritory" without underscore worked. it is not internal nor display name but worked.